# msal-angualr returns 401 when accessing remote API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

When working on a local copy of our Angular application we need to access the api on the dev server.  However since upgrading to using msal-angular this does not work anymore, it returns 401 and goes into a redirection loop.

I'm not sure if there is a configuration we are missing to allow this to work.  It worked fine when we were using adal but we need V2 tokens on the api now.

```
export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
];

...

imports: [
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: 'Azure-App-Id',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Azure-Tenant-Id',
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      popUp: false,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap
    })
],
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true }
],

...
```

The above is my configuration in app.module.ts.

This works fine when I run my angular application from http://localhost:4200 against my asp.net core web api run from visual studio on https://localhost:5600.

It also runs fine when deployed on the server.  However if I change the Angular app in dev environment to use the servers api (http://localhost:4200 -> https://www.api.azurewebsite.net), we always get authentication errors as the Angular app does not send the bearer token like it does on the other two cases.

Hopefully this is enough details.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to give us more information that this.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the issue with with msal-angular's interceptor.  I guess it does the right thing and the scopes are empty when going cross-domain.

We created our own interceptor from the msal-angular code to inject the scope if we are in development.

Thank you.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { MsalService, BroadcastService } from '@azure/msal-angular';


@Injectable()
export class CustomMsalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: MsalService, private broadcastService: BroadcastService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (req.url.indexOf('geocode.arcgis.com') >= 0) {
            return next.handle(req);
        } else {

            let scopes = this.auth.getScopesForEndpoint(req.url);

            this.auth.verbose('Url: ' + req.url + ' maps to scopes: ' + scopes);
            if (scopes === null) {
                if (req.url.indexOf('azurewebsites')) {
                    scopes = ['****  APPLICAITON (CLIENT) ID *****'];
                } else {
                    return next.handle(req);
                }
            }
            const tokenStored = this.auth.getCachedTokenInternal(scopes);
            if (tokenStored && tokenStored.token) {
                req = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenStored.token}`,
                    }
                });
                return next.handle(req).do(event => { }, err => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
                        const scopes1 = this.auth.getScopesForEndpoint(req.url);
                        const tokenStored1 = this.auth.getCachedTokenInternal(scopes1);
                        if (tokenStored1 && tokenStored1.token) {
                            this.auth.clearCacheForScope(tokenStored.token);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return Observable.fromPromise(this.auth.acquireTokenSilent(scopes).then(token => {
                    const JWT = `Bearer ${token}`;
                    return req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            Authorization: JWT,
                        },
                    });
                })).mergeMap(req1 => next.handle(req1).do(event => { }, err => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
                        const scopes2 = this.auth.getScopesForEndpoint(req1.url);
                        const tokenStored2 = this.auth.getCachedTokenInternal(scopes2);
                        if (tokenStored2 && tokenStored2.token) {
                            this.auth.clearCacheForScope(tokenStored2.token);
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the interceptor code, so others could benefit from your question and answer? 
Thanks

Comment: @bruno_cw I added the code we use.  We just got the msal-angualr code and replaced the interceptor.  When scopes are null (which in dev they are) we check if the proxy.config points to an Azure website, if it does we add the Azure AD Client Id registration for the app.  That was the only change we made.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, for now I made own implementation of MsalInterceptor.
Vote for wildcard in protectedResourceMap https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1776
This is my custom code block:

```
// #region own workaround in order not to put every api endpoint url to settings
if (!scopes && req.url.startsWith(this.settingsService.apiUrl)) {
  scopes = [this.auth.getCurrentConfiguration().auth.clientId];
}
// #endregion

// If there are no scopes set for this request, do nothing.
if (!scopes) {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```